# Post-Builds in TFS Team Build best practice

Tags: msbuild, build-process, tfsbuild, post-build

i have a question about Post-Builds. We have a Post-Build in project settings. This Post-Build task compress JavaScript because of Web Application performance. Assembly path is assigned by variable *$(YUICompressorDLLPath)*.

Generally it works fine from developer machine but how should I do it from TFS Team Build. When I start the Team Build it ends with error because the assembly is on the build machine on other place as on developer machine. I tried overwrite the variable over MSBuild Arguments but it seems it doesn't work.

What is the best practice, how is to accomplish this?

Regards

Anton Kalcik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice, on my opinion is to keep the directory structure on build server same as on developer machine. On this way is working everything fine, because of relative paths. For more information to see how to ensure generated file will be deployed see also: [Deploy generated files in TFS Build Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843785/deploy-generated-files-in-tfs-build-server)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should change **$(YUICompressorDLLPath)** ***$(OutDir)\$(TargetFileName)***

Comment: I don't think it will be helpful in my situation. The referenced assemblies are in other place in TFS and the path is relative one.